# Stop Bootstrap3 button text to turn underline on mouseover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to stop bootstrap 3 default button to be underline when mouseover, but no success at all. Here is my CSS and HTML code:

```css
.btn-default:hover {
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a href="#tech-skills">Tech Skills</a>
</button>
```

Notice that I could change the :hover background-color, but looks like the propertie font-style is not referred to what I'm trying to change.

Here is how the button looks like:

[Button Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OvwS.png)

Comment: `text-decoration: none` is the rule you're looking for. Apply that to the `a` tag, where the underline is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlines are controlled by the text-decoration CSS attribute, not the font-style attribute. Also, the underline is not being applied to the button tag itself, but the anchor tag within the button.

See this demo:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a href="#tech-skills">Tech Skills</a>
</button>
```

Comment: You're right. And the specific one that I needed was the a:hover {text-decoration: none}

Comment: @EsdrasEmanuel Depending on which CSS rules take precedent, that may indeed be necessary. Please select my answer, so others know your question has been resolved. :)